# MediaRecorder crashes on start

Tags: android, android-emulator, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

i've searched many topics but no straight answer.

I have this code :

```
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

    recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    if(!mStartRecording)
    {
        btn.setText("Stop Recording");
        try {
            recorder.prepare();

        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
        mStartRecording = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.setText("Start Recording");
        mStartRecording = false;
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
```

And i've added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

(saw somewhere that adding STORAGE solved it, no good for me)

I'm developing on API Level 7 (Android 2.1)

stack trace says "start faild"
Stack trace :

```
    04-26 19:27:41.955: D/dalvikvm(890): GC freed 809 objects / 58272 bytes in 433ms
04-26 19:27:44.772: D/dalvikvm(890): GC freed 95 objects / 3936 bytes in 371ms
04-26 19:28:54.973: E/MediaRecorder(890): start failed: -1
04-26 19:28:54.993: D/AndroidRuntime(890): Shutting down VM
04-26 19:28:54.993: W/dalvikvm(890): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-26 19:28:54.993: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at shibby.whisper.WhisperGameActivity.recordAudio(WhisperGameActivity.java:94)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  ... 21 more
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
04-26 19:28:55.105: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  ... 25 more
04-26 19:28:55.223: I/dalvikvm(890): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-26 19:28:55.335: I/dalvikvm(890): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-26 19:28:57.123: I/Process(890): Sending signal. PID: 890 SIG: 9
```

Please help.

Comment: provide all the stack trace please

Comment: what can you find in /data/anr/traces.txt

Comment: this may seem dumb, but i have no idea where to find that file. is it in the workspace?

Comment: in a console : adb shell pull /data/anr/traces.txt. Then you will find the file in your current directory.

Comment: i tried through CMD, dosen't work. sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt. sorry

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: plug your android as a mass storage and get the file /data/anr/traces.txt

Comment: Are you sure there is no other recording pending ?

Comment: Ya it's an empty project with basicly only that and facebook login

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10572/discussion-between-snicolas-and-eric-itzhak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I guess you initialized mStartRecording to true.

Thus your `if` is going into the `else` block. In it, you stop a brand new instance of MediaRecorder and the state diagram doesn't allow that.

Make your media recorder a field of your class. And initialize properly your mStartRecording boolean variable to false. Re instanciate your media recorder only if your field is null.

```
if( recorder == null ) {
   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

   recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
}//if
if(!mStartRecording) {
    btn.setText("Stop Recording");
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        mStartRecording = true;
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//catch
} else {
    btn.setText("Start Recording");
    mStartRecording = false;
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}//else
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention, i thought it's a given. the mStartRecording is false.

Comment: try to add some traces (Log.d) statements to see what your program does. Does it crash in the if or else block

Comment: mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
         mFileName += "/audiorecordtest4.3gp"; calling this in onCreated method

Comment: try it on a device, try creating the file and try a different path.

Comment: I can chat about this problem if you want

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the `start` function in the same block as `prepare` function. maybe there's an exception blocking prepare from executing and goes directly to start thus causing an `IllegalStateException`.

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());


    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: is your setoutputfile after setaudioencoder? try changing that!

Comment: an error can occur if your mstartrecording is initialized to true. is it initialized to false?

Comment: are you doing this on the emulator? could be a sd card issue. have you tried it on a device yet?

Comment: I am running on an emulator. i've set it enabled for audio recording. and though they documation mentions the emulator can't do that, i've read that it actully can. and i've set the Emulator with 100mb of SD.

Answer (score 1):

i am using the following code,works perfectly for me..

```
protected void startRecording() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    i++;
     mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
     mFileName += "/audiorecordtest"+i+".3gp";
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

      try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IllegalStateException called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepare() failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

      recorder.start();
}

 private void stopRecording() {
     recorder.stop();
     recorder.release();
     recorder = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

These methods must arrange the order it will run. Here:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your recorder only when it is prepared :

```
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        mStartRecording = true;
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Error when preparing or starting recorder", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is because I had missed a slash while setting the filename for the recorded audio.

change

```
this.fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
this.fileName += "yourfilename.3gp";
```

to

```
this.fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
this.fileName += "/yourfilename.3gp";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem because of my SurfaceView has been made invisible. So make it Visible

```
  mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Must first call `setOutputFile()` , and then call other methods.

and you must create file before all.

Comment: This is not correct. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder), first, the source type should be selected, then the output format should be decided, and then this rest of the attributes should be set.