# Calling MediaRecorder crashes app in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I am trying to create a class that sets and starts audio recording but as soon as I click the button the app crashes. Iv isolated the problem to where I set the parameters for the MediRecorder.

```
private void startRec() throws IOException {
    if (mrecorder!=null)
        mrecorder.release();

    mrecorder= new MediaRecorder();

->  mrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    /*
    mrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mrecorder.setOutputFile(MFILE);

    mrecorder.prepare();
    mrecorder.start();

    */
}
```

It crashes when the line with the arrow above the start of the notes is executed. I added the following permission to the manifest as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Any help much appreciated.

UPDATED LOGCAT

[ 05-12 00:39:13.299 30086:30158 D/         ]
                                                                  ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
05-12 00:39:13.309 30086-30158/record66.record6 D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
05-12 00:39:13.319 30086-30086/record66.record6 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-12 00:39:13.319 30086-30158/record66.record6 D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : record66.record6
05-12 00:39:13.359 30086-30086/record66.record6 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-12 00:39:13.389 30086-30086/record66.record6 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@682466c time:234401322
05-12 00:39:15.749 30086-30086/record66.record6 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
05-12 00:39:15.879 30086-30086/record66.record6 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
05-12 00:39:15.929 30086-30086/record66.record6 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-12 00:39:15.939 30086-30086/record66.record6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: record66.record6, PID: 30086
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                      at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:488)
                                                                      at record66.record6.MainActivity.startRec(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                      at record66.record6.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
05-12 00:39:17.909 30086-30086/record66.record6 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30086 SIG: 9

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340400/mediarecorder-crashes-on-start

Comment: whats the crash log?

Comment: What logcat says, post that so we can help.

Comment: @Dhrupal  I'm new to this and I'm not sure which log cat you are referring to but I am running the program directly on my phone and when it crashes it gives me the generic  "an error has occurred this program will shut down"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see what [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#systemLog) is.

And let us know what error you are getting. So can help.

---

```
package com.example.dhrupalpatel.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
MediaRecorder mrecorder;
boolean mStartRecording=false;

Button start, stop;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start =(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void startRec() throws IOException {
   boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
    File sdCardDirectory= Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(mExternalStorageAvailable && !sdCardDirectory.exists())
    {
        sdCardDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    File f= new File(sdCardDirectory.getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3");
    if( mrecorder == null ) {
        mrecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

        mrecorder.setOutputFile(f.getPath());
        mrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    }
    if(!mStartRecording) {

        try {
            mrecorder.prepare();
            mrecorder.start();
            mStartRecording = true;
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRec() throws IOException {

    if(mStartRecording) {
        mStartRecording = false;
        mrecorder.stop();
        mrecorder.reset();
        mrecorder.release();
        mrecorder = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.start:
            try {
                startRec();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            try {
                stopRec();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Edited original post let me know if that is it

Comment: Thank you I will try it. What I'd the reason my code didn't work? Is it because I never implemented the on click listener?

Comment: I added the code that you made but still running into the same problem. I updated the logcat with the latest from your code

Comment: Where you are testing the app? in emulator?

Comment: Directly on my phone Galaxy S6

Comment: Error is on making  mkdir() line. Please do check. Corrected code.

Comment: I get a warning that says "Result of File.mkdir() is ignored". How do I fix it?

Comment: Read somewhere. " Android Marshmallow you have to go on "Settings > Apps > Your App > Permissions" and enble Microphone permission."

Comment: Can you accept and up my answer, if it is worked for you. :)