# AndroidsetAudioSource failed

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I tried [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) to record audio from the microphone.
When I start recording `java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed` always appears. 
I also add this permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782786/android-mediarecorder-setaudiosource-failed

Answer (score 0):

Please see [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129254/calling-mediarecorder-crashes-app-in-androidstudio/37153206#37153206). I have shown code to start and stop record. Also Oleg Khalidov's link can help you. And android dev site [solution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually give the app permission to access the microphone and file system (Settings -> Apps -> 'Your App' -> Permissions)